# JSON returns Object Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, local-storage

I currently have a JSON object I am trying to use. Here is me stringifying it because localStorage can only have strings:

```js
$http.post('http://localhost:8000/refresh', {
  name: $scope.name,
  email: $scope.email,
  token: $rootScope.devToken,
  platform: ionic.Platform.platform()
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log("Saving profile");

  window.localStorage.setItem("UserProfile", JSON.stringify(response.data));

  $state.go('home');
});
```

When I `console.log(response.data)`, the correct data comes out.
Then here is me getting it out of *localStorage*:

```js
var temp = window.localStorage.getItem("UserProfile");
var profile = JSON.parse(temp);
console.log("Profile: " + profile);
```

When I `console.log(profile)` I get Object object. What am I doing wrong? When I `console.log(temp)` I get a huge string of correct data. But I don't want it to be a string. I need it to be back into an object.

EDIT:
JSON:

```js
[
  {
   userProfileID: 1,
   firstName: 'Austin',
   lastName: 'Hunter',
   email: 'ahunasdfgk.com',
   token: '',
   platform: '',
   password: 'inc3',
   companyProfileID: 1,
   authentication: '',
   UserTopics: [
    {
     topicID: 1,
     topicName: 'Needs Maintenance',
     alertLevel: 'Urgent',
     TopicDepartments: [
      {
       departmentID: 1,
       departmentName: 'Shop',
       required: false,
       DepartmentUsers: [
        {
         userProfileID: 1,
         firstName: 'Austin',
         lastName: 'Hunter',
         email: 'ahunook.com',
         token: '',
         platform: '',
         companyProfileID: 1
        }, {
         userProfileID: 2,
         firstName: 'Ashley',
         lastName: 'Jeanette',
         email: 'ashlhgfdail.com',
         token: '',
         platform: '',
         companyProfileID: 1
        }
       ]
      }
     ]
    }, {
     topicID: 2,
     topicName: 'Help',
     alertLevel: 'Urgent',
     TopicDepartments: [
      {
       departmentID: 1,
       departmentName: 'Shop',
       required: false,
       DepartmentUsers: [
        {
         userProfileID: 1,
         firstName: 'Austin',
         lastName: 'Hunter',
         email: 'afafaf@oook.com',
         token: '',
         platform: '',
         companyProfileID: 1
        }
       ]
      }, {
       departmentID: 2,
       departmentName: 'Office',
       required: false,
       DepartmentUsers: [
        {
         userProfileID: 1,
         firstName: 'Ashley',
         lastName: 'Jeanette',
         email: 'ashfafaff.com',
         token: '',
         platform: '',
         companyProfileID: 1
        }
       ]
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ];
```

And console.log(profile) gives me this:

```js
[Log] Array (1) (controllers.js, line 65)
0 Object

UserTopics: [Object, Object] (2)

_id: "57e078cc62e223290851c2c1"

authentication: ""

companyProfileID: 1

email: "ahun______.com"

firstName: "Austin"

lastName: "Hunter"

password: "inco_______23"

platform: ""

token: ""

userProfileID: 1

Object Prototype

__defineGetter__(propertyName, getterFunction)

__defineSetter__(propertyName, setterFunction)

__lookupGetter__(propertyName)

__lookupSetter__(propertyName)

constructor: function()

hasOwnProperty(propertyName)

isPrototypeOf(property)

propertyIsEnumerable(propertyName)

toLocaleString()

toString()

valueOf()

Array Prototype
No Properties.

Object Prototype

__defineGetter__(propertyName, getterFunction)

__defineSetter__(propertyName, setterFunction)

__lookupGetter__(propertyName)

__lookupSetter__(propertyName)

constructor: function()

hasOwnProperty(propertyName)

isPrototypeOf(property)

propertyIsEnumerable(propertyName)

toLocaleString()

toString()

valueOf()
```

Comment: Remove the string in the log - it's just how the log outputs. `console.log(profile)` - or `console.log("profile", profile)`

Comment: You're casting an object to a string while logging, the result is `"[Object object]"`… That's all that's wrong.

Comment: That works. Would accessing data still be the same? profile.email or profile.name?

Comment: For anyone with my same issue, Let me clarify. I had a array of objects with array of objects inside of it. The reason I couldn't just do profile.email was because it was an array. I have to do profile[0].email to get the email. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `console.log(profile)`. your approach converts the "profile" to String. hence gives `[Object Object]` . in your case, to obtain `email` please use profile[0].email as your call return an array instead of a JSON Object.

Comment: That works. Would accessing data still be the same? profile.email or profile.name?

Comment: ofcourse it will work for `profile.email / profile.name` if you have them in your JSON.

Comment: add your JSON please.

Comment: JSON added. Just look above

Comment: For anyone with my same issue, Let me clarify. I had a array of objects with array of objects inside of it. The reason I couldn't just do profile.email was because it was an array. I have to do profile[0].email to get the email. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: exactly. sorry for late response.

Answer (score 1):

your approach is correct

```
console.log( profile); will print correct object
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be a Cross-origin-policy issue.Have a look at this article.

https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document

Comment: No, it isn't. and this could better be a comment instead of an answer.